# In while loop speech_recognition sr.listen drasticly slows down

Tags: python, speech-recognition, pyttsx3

I have a problem that when I use SpeechRecognition library in python and when I want to put `r.listen(source)`in while loop my code drasticly slows down.

```
import speech_recognition as sr
import pyttsx3 as p
import random
from talk import *


r = sr.Recognizer()
engine = p.init()


    
with sr.Microphone() as source:
    while 0<1:
        text = r.listen(source)
        try:
            recognised_text = r.recognize_google(text)
            print(recognised_text)
            if (recognised_text =="hello" or recognised_text =="hi"):
                greeting()
        except sr.UnknownValueError:
            print("")
        except sr.RequestError as e:
            print("")
```

Comment: How exactly does it "slow down"? How do you define that?

Comment: first two times loop works perfectly after those two when I say command it processes it for almost a minute and after that time I get the response. What should I do to make it as efficient as the first two attempts?

Comment: I say hello and the program responds instantly after the second time the same, but after the third time it takes more than a minute to respond back @go2nirvana

Comment: You can use offline speech recognition to get instant response, network based libraries have issues with latency

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev what kind of offline speech recognition library are you talking about?